# Word for a discussion-ending comment

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that defines something that is said that ends discussions because it can't be argued with. It's very annoying and I must find the word. My brother does it. He will say, "it's all relative" to just about anything.

Comment: I agree; I hate it when that happens.  It's like when Billo the Reilly says to a guest : "we'll just have to agree to disagree" as a way to shut up someone who is speaking an opinion he doesn't like, or bringing up facts that he can't refute.

Comment: _Whatever_ seems to be the popular discussion-ending comment nowadays.

Comment: Find a very distant relative and come back with eg 'Does that include Uncle Quentin?' // A 'conversation-ender' though really this is usually not entirely accurate. Exceptions may be ‘Geronimo!’, Aaargh!' ... though these are not really comments.

Comment: A subcategory may be **conversation stopper**: "A remark that stops the natural flow of the conversation because it is unexpected and in some way causes embarrassment or shock" [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/conversation-stopper)

Comment: Lots of phrases: mic drop, last word/final word.

Answer (score 0):

Buzzword. Or in this case, buzz-line?

A word, sentence or manner of speech people will use, to confidently end an argument or discussion. When in reality, they were likely out of ammo and chose to retreat.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).